# How to angular translate ng-model property value?

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

In my controller $http service data is assigned to $scope as:

```
$scope.project = data.data;
```

In my view for a text box I have defined:

```
ng-model="project.name"
```

How do I translate ng-model value of `project.name` using angular-translate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
ng-model="project.name|translate"
```

Comment: I had tried that earlier and translation works but got nonassign error: ``Error: [ngModel:nonassign] Expression 'project.name | translate' is non-assignable``

Comment: in controller use this :  project.name=$filter('translate')('project.name')

Comment: ``$scope.project.name = $filter('translate')($scope.project.name);`` on controller resolved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: `ng-model="{{ project.name | translate }}"` worked for me.
also more info at: https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/wiki/Dynamize-your-translations#parametrizing-the-translate-filter

Comment: @gkc `ng-model="{{ project.name | translate }}"` throws `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{'`

Answer (score 3):

angular-translate gives you access to a special filter (which is the same one you use in your markup) exactly for this. Just inject `$filter` in your controller and do something like this:

```
$filter('translate')(translationId[, interpolateParams])
```